# What is a proper way to upgrade from  Flash CS4 project to Flash CS5?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

I'm wondering if there is a proper way to upgrade from Flash CS4 to CS5. What I did was just open existing CS4 project in CS5 and saved it as CS5.  It seems to work but I'm wondering:  did I miss something in the transition? Do I need to make additional modifications for project to work better in CS5?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is obviously  : NO.
you dont need to do anything.

Comment: You never know. From experience, even when a software company assures you that everything should upgrade smoothly, some issues come up. So I just want to see if there were such issues.